# Разница в работе с конструктором и без него

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Зачем нужны конструкторы, если есть второй метод и чем они отличаются?
Первый способ создания объекта:

```
function createUser(name, age) {
 return {
  name: name,
  age: age,
  displayInfo: function () {
     console.log("Имя: " + this.name + " возраст: " + this.age);
  },
  driveCar: function (car) {
     console.log(this.name + " ведет машину " + car.name);
  }
 };
}
```

Второй способ создания объекта:

```
function User(name, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.displayInfo = function () {
   console.log("Имя: " + this.name + "; возраст: " + this.age);
 };
 this.driveCar = function (car) {
   console.log(this.name + " ведет машину " + car.name);
 };
}
```

Comment: в вашем случае, принципиально вроде как и ничем

Comment: Будет разный прототип.

Comment: @ThisMan Я понимаю, как работает код и в том и в том случае)
Интересно, какие-то более углубленные вещи узнать, это просто пример, чтобы можно было понять, о чем я говорю.

Comment: И, например, методы лучше создавать в прототипе, это банально экономичнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Зачем нужны конструкторы, если есть второй метод и чем они отличаются?

Как раз-таки "второй метод" - это и есть самый настоящий конструктор, а вот первый метод - это просто функция, возвращающая объект. По существу она, конечно, тоже конструктор (своего рода), но по факту есть различия:

1. В первом случае `new createuser() instanceof createUser` вернет `false`, а во втором `new User instanceof User` вернет `true`

```js
function createUser(name, age) {
 return {
  name: name,
  age: age,
  displayInfo: function () {
     console.log("Имя: " + this.name + " возраст: " + this.age);
  },
  driveCar: function (car) {
     console.log(this.name + " ведет машину " + car.name);
  }
 };
}

function User(name, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.displayInfo = function () {
   console.log("Имя: " + this.name + "; возраст: " + this.age);
 };
 this.driveCar = function (car) {
   console.log(this.name + " ведет машину " + car.name);
 };
}

console.log(new createUser instanceof createUser);
console.log(new User instanceof User);
```

2. В первом случае теряется прототип и, как следствие, вся информация о конструкторе (собственно, отсюда вытекает первый пункт)

```js
function createUser(name, age) {
 return {
  name: name,
  age: age,
  displayInfo: function () {
     console.log("Имя: " + this.name + " возраст: " + this.age);
  },
  driveCar: function (car) {
     console.log(this.name + " ведет машину " + car.name);
  }
 };
}

let user = new createUser();
console.log(user.__proto__ === createUser.prototype);

function User(name, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.displayInfo = function () {
   console.log("Имя: " + this.name + "; возраст: " + this.age);
 };
 this.driveCar = function (car) {
   console.log(this.name + " ведет машину " + car.name);
 };
}

let user2 = new User();
console.log(user2.__proto__ === User.prototype);
```

С другой стороны, если вас не интересуют прототипы и пользоваться оператором `instanceof` вы не планируете, то беспокоиться Вам не о чем. Первый вариант, несмотря на все свои недостатки, вполне имеет право на жизнь и, более того, *возможно*, в некоторых случаях будет даже предпочтителен (однако с ходу вот так вот пример придумать не могу).

P.S. Скорее всего это не все различия, возможно о чем-то я позабыл

Comment: лучше добавить, что во втором случае методы все равно не записываются в прототип, следовательно создаются для каждого экземпляра, что не очень эффективно

Comment: @ThisMan так-то оно так, да только вопрос не об этом (может придти Grundy и сказать, что пол-ответа можно запросто выбросить :) )

Comment: просто, это одно из отличий существенных в пользу именно второго варианта

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Перепутал код местами)
Вроде бы начинает проясняться!)

Comment: @Friendly33 На будущее. С точки зрения терминологии JavaScript (ECMAScript) конструктор ничего **явно** возвращать не должен. Иначе говоря, если у вас есть функция, в теле которой есть слово `return` (до которого доходит исполнение), то это уже не конструктор. Ну точнее как бы блин, это все равно может быть конструктор, но только работать он уже будет не так, как "настоящий" конструктор в JavaScript. Запутанно это все в общем :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, Grundy пришел и говорит, что большую часть ответа действительно можно выбросить :)

Comment: @Grundy надеюсь, что это сарказм о_О

Comment: @smellyshovel, надейся ;-)